# jquery - add default/active link on refresh

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I used this old tutorial as a reference for my website:
[Scrolling Clouds](http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/116_parallax/tutorial-source-files/tut-index.html)

The problem is that when I open/refresh the page, there is no default active link.
So I have to click one of the links to become active.
I would like to have default link on the page load and keep the current link active when refreshing.
Now when I refresh the page the current content stays but there's no active link item.

Here's the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.link').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1300);  
    $('a.link').removeClass('selected');  
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;  
  });  
});
```

So my simple question is; how to define the 'selected' link item on page load. 
And how to keep the current item active on page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the url of the page and strip the hash. Check the hash against the ids of your divs, and add the active class to the matched div.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, every link click is rendering a `return false`, causing the browser not to navigate to the hashed address. If you instead allowed the links to go to the hashes, you would be able to move your scrolling logic to `hashchange`:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
   // scroll to the proper div as identified by window.location.hash
   // and set active link
});
```

In this way, the hash will remain when you refresh the page, you will get browser history compatibility for your navigation, and you will be able to bookmark a certain active panel.

To prevent the browser from immediately scrolling to the hashed name, you may want to hijack the click event to manually set `window.location.hash`, to allow your script to pick up that hash change and do the smooth scrolling, and return false, to prevent the default browser action. This way, you also fall back to standard HTML in case javascript isn't enabled in the client.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Purmou, however this solution doesn't directly apply to your case. Clicking links in your example contains a `return false`, so the hash isn't changed in your case. You could remove the return, but I think it wouldn't be a perfect solution because it causes the browser to scroll to the element with the specified `id` (I could be wrong about that, you should test it).

How about trying the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)? You could use the `pushState` method in your `click` handler to set the address manually and then, after refresh, use it to identify the link which should be marked as active.